# Unable to connect to local server

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, pycharm

I am working on a project which uses `pycharm` and Google Cloud for back end. While debugging the application , I am unable to connect to localhost location `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, and instead keeps waiting forever.

In the console window, I see the below warnings. I would like to know what is preventing connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and also if the warnings listed below have any impact?.

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.38)
INFO     2017-07-05 18:25:44,914 api_server.py:272] Starting API server 
at: http://localhost:51197
INFO     2017-07-05 18:25:44,922 dispatcher.py:205] Starting module 
"internal-api" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2017-07-05 18:25:44,929 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin 
          server at: http://localhost:8000
WARNING  2017-07-05 18:25:44,929 devappserver2.py:766] No default 
          module found. Ignoring.
pydev debugger: process 940 is connecting

pydev debugger: process 941 is connecting  



/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml
    .py:73: 
       RuntimeWarning: Parent module '_pydevd_bundle' not found while handling absolute import
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py:79: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '_pydevd_bundle' not found while handling absolute import
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py:86: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '_pydevd_bundle' not found while handling absolute import
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py:93: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '_pydevd_bundle' not found while handling absolute import
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Can't believe myself, it is a hidden breakpoint which i could not see it which kept the serve waiting.